# Word-Wraping for the calendar

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, development, sharepoint-foundation, css

[image][image]

The first image named calendarSample1 is a screenshot of the sharepoint calendar in IE10. The second image named calendarSample2 is from Google Chrome.

I am trying to make the text within the calendar wrap. The code I used is this:

> .ms-acal-item{
>     word-wrap:break-word!important;
>     height:inherit!important;
>     font-size:9px!important;}

I shrunk the text to help fit it in the date-block.

Am I missing something to make it work in other browsers (such as  firefox and google chrome)? Why does it only work on IE?

I'm using Sharepoint Foundation 2013

Comment: hi! can you post your full CSS including the part that shrinks the cells as well. I want to reproduce your problem first.

Comment: @DenisMolodtsov ya sure: 
<code>
.ms-acal-month-top{font-size:9px!important} 
body{ width:1200px!important; margin:0 auto 0 auto; font-family:"Calibri", serif!important; font-size:8pt!important; } 

/* min-height is needed to show the content WITHIN the pop-up dialog */ 
#s4-workspace{ width:inherit!important; min-height:315px!important; font-size:8pt!important; } 

#sideNavBox{font-size:8pt!important;}
<code>

Comment: that's weird. I've got the same behavior in both IE 10 and Chrome. I've got the same situation as you have on the second screenshot. But my cells are much wider than yours even when my browser window is very narrow. So, I guess, you have more styles affecting your cells then you gave us :(

Comment: <pre>div.ms-promlink-body{height: 80px;}
div.ms-tileview-tile-root{height: 85px !important; width:85px !important;}

div.ms-tileview-tile-content, div.ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox,  div.ms-tileview-tile-content> a> div> span {
 height:80px !important;
 width:80px !important;}

div.ms-tileview-tile-content > a > div > img{
 max-width:100%;
 width:80px !important;}

/* this height is to display the desciption. Make it match the height of the img */
ul.ms-tileview-tile-detailsListMedium{
 height:80px;
 padding:0;}

li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium{
 font-size:8pt;
 line-height:16px;}
</pre>

Comment: div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumExpanded, div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextLargeCollapsed, div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextLargeExpanded{padding:3px;}

div.ms-tileview-tile-titleTextMediumCollapsed{
background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #002E4F;font-size:8pt;line-height:16px;min-height:36px;min-width:97px;padding-left:3px;position:absolute;top:-36px;margin-left:-2px!important;}

li.ms-tileview-tile-descriptionMedium{
    font-size:8pt;
    line-height:14px;
    padding:3px;}

/* this adjusts the image being used */
.ms-tileview-tile-content img{width:80px!important; height:80px!important;}

Comment: the code above is the last bit, however, the reason why I didn't include it was because it was relative to a previous problem. Sorry for the mess but as you can see, I have a hard time trying to tidy the code up (I looked at the help page and it still wont work as intended)

Answer (score 1):

So far I could only think of this way:

```
.ms-acal-title>a, .ms-acal-title
{       
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* css-3 */    
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap; /* Opera 4-6 */    
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; /* Opera 7 */    
    word-wrap: break-word; /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */ 
}
```

I think, there might still be a problem with the height. The contents of the calendar cell might go beyond the cell itself. So, I think there is a good reason there is no word-wrap in the standard SharePoint style. If you are satisfied with your first screenshot - try adding several items in one cell to test it.

Comment: It didn't work. Thank you for trying though. I'll just cut my loses.